# How to add CSS class to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, redmine

I'm trying to change the style using bootstrap in the following Redmine account menu List.

I want to apply dropdown to 'my account' and 'sign out'.

[image]

**Redmine.rb**

```
Redmine::MenuManager.map :account_menu do |menu|
menu.push :login, :signin_path, :if => Proc.new { !User.current.logged? }
menu.push :register, :register_path, :if => Proc.new { !User.current.logged? && 
Setting.self_registration? }
menu.push :my_account, { :controller => 'my', :action => 'account' }, :if => Proc.new { 
User.current.logged? }
menu.push :logout, :signout_path, :html => {:method => 'post'}, :if => Proc.new { 
User.current.logged? }
end
```

**base.html.erb**

```
<div id="account">
    <%= render_menu :account_menu -%>
</div>
```

**view-source**

```
<div id="account">    
  <ul>
     <li><a class="my-account" href="/my/account">My account</a></li>
     <li><a class="logout" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/logout">Sign out</a></li>   
 </ul> 
</div>
```

How can I add class="dropdown-menu" to `<ul>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to modify Redmine, there are multiple ways.

1. Use a plugin: https://redmine.org/plugins/redmine_view_customize 
   it lets you run javascript or add css on specific page, then add class via jquery selector, for that case:`$("#account > ul").addClass("dropdown-menu");`
2. Create your own plugin and use Deface plugin https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_base_deface to modify existing layout. (if your plugin is of public good, you can share it with us via github and Redmine's plugin list on https://www.redmine.org/plugins)
3. Modify your existing installation of Redmine, but create a .patch file https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Patch